# How to post text on Facebook wall when login with different id

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am implementing facebook sharing in my application but getting problem like,i am able to post on facebook when login with my facebook id, but when i am login with different email id not able to post on facebook. This is working only with one facebook id.

Here is my code:

```
public void postOnFacebook(Session session)
    {
        if(session.isOpened()){
            if (session != null){


                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest((Activity) this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);

                Bundle post = new Bundle();

                post.putString("message","Hello Everyone");

                Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                    }
                };

                Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", post, 
                        HttpMethod.POST, callback);

                RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
                task.execute();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                logout();

            }
        }

    }

    public void logout()
    {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null){
            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            session = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: when you login to facebook it saves Session of logged user in "SessionManager", Clear session will solve your problem

Comment: I have already clear the session after posting from one id even i have tried after uninstall the app and there is no facebook app in my phone as well.I think its working only for that id, on which i have created the app id for facebook authentication.

Comment: closeAndClearTokenInformation() try this
which mentioned in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Session/

Comment: @ManjuKumari you can post with Your Apps Created id in Facebook but you can not use other is for That You need to Go through Review Of App

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the "Make app public feature". Just select the right side button to enable it to yes. Also, this will make the green circle by the side of your app name be in solid green.
After this step only the app will be accessible by any facebook account. Else, till this is not done, it will be defaultly accessible to the account in which the app was registered.
 [image]

Comment: @ManjuKumari are both accounts related? Means one friends with the other?

Comment: That's the reason.. You need to have the accounts... see it's simillar to you are trying to post on the wall of a person whom you are not freind with. The facebook will ask you to Add him/her as a freind then only you get access rights to post to their walls.

Comment: Hey, I am trying to post on my facebook wall that means post on that wall whome you are login with. When i am using one of my old app id it is working fine but not working with new created app ids

Comment: I am only able to post through my developer account,when i am using different account, not able to post feed on that account's facebook wall.

Comment: Ok... I too faced a simillar issue. It seems facebook guys have changed some sort of settings with the newer api version. Shall let you know asap.

Comment: Which version of facebook sdk do you use? Is it > 15 ?

Comment: I have used the latest one 3.17 and old one as well,previously created app ids working fine, facing problem only with new created app ids.